# Add several objects in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

My Django model is as follow:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Section(models.Model):
    page_id = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SubSection(models.Model):
    section_id = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And I'd like to add a new `Page` in django Admin with the possibility to add several `Section` in which I can add several `SubSection`.

I already succeed to create a page where we can add a `Page` in which we can add several `Section` but it asks only for the name of the `Section` and there is no possibility to add a `SubSection` in the same page.

I tried this:

```
class SectionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Section
    extra = 3

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SectionInline]

admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

But I can not add `SubSectionInline` into `SectionInline`.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this using standard django admin app.

All django admin let you do is to add Page with many Sections.
Maybe adding many SubSections in Sections adding page would do what you want?

You need to add:

```
class SubSectionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SubSection
    extra = 3

class SectionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SubSectionInline]

admin.site.register(Section, SectionAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the Django admin does not support inlines within inlines. You can manage Sections inline with a Page, and Subsections inline with a Section, but not both at the same time.